# Borrowing or raising funds against ISOs

Tags: loans, employee-stock-options, collateral

I have some ISOs that are exercised (early exercised/bought) from two different companies I worked at. Their current values are around $15k each.

These amounts aren't enough to transact with secondary market brokers like Sharespost or Equityzen. But are these valid assets to borrow against? For ex, could I potentially offer these to banks to raise funds (perhaps at low interest rates)?

Comment: I can't imagine any bank would do this. (1) The people who handle loans probably don't know anything about how to value illiquid stock, and (2) it is just too volatile to borrow against.